# Is denial of entry in the US appealable?

Tags: united-states, immigration, appeal

Suppose X possesses a valid visa to the US and enter a US port of entry.

However at this point a CBP officer determines X to be inadmissible to the US for some reason.
Can X appeal this reason to a higher authority? Some sort of a court review while they don't deport X?